# PHP foreach with table rows

Tags: php, foreach

I have this PHP script here

```
$z = range(2, 123);
echo '<table width="100%">';
foreach($z as $x){

echo '<td><a href="http://www.mysite.net/' . $x . '/"><img src="http://www.mysite.net/' . $x . '/5.jpg" width=200></a></td>';
}

echo '</table>';
```

What I am trying to do is get 6 items in the table row and then a new row...how would I do this?

Thanks,
J

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here the [modulo operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) comes in. You can divide and calculate the remainder. Everytime the remainder is `0` you add a new row:

```
$z = range(2, 123);
echo '<table width="100%">';
echo '<tr>';
$cnt = 2;
foreach($z as $x){
if ( ($cnt - 2) % 6 == 0 ) {
echo '</tr><tr>';
}
$cnt++;
echo '<td><a href="http://www.mysite.net/' . $x . '/"><img src="http://www.mysite.net/' . $x . '/5.jpg" width=200></a></td>';
}
echo '</tr>';
echo '</table>';
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want your codes nice and clean, always separate data manipulation from presentation code. Thus, move as much logic away from output, as possible.
So, first prepare your data

```
<?
$data = range(2, 123);
$data = array_chunk($data, 6);
?>
```

and then output it

```
<table width="100%">
<? foreach($data as $chunk): ?>
  <tr>
<? foreach($chunk as $val): ?>
    <td>
      <a href="/<?=$val?>/"><img src="/<?=$val?>/5.jpg" width=200></a>
    </td>
<? endforeach ?>
  </tr>
<? endforeach ?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
$z = range(2, 123);
echo '<table width="100%"><tr>';
foreach($z as $x){

    if( ($x - 2) % 6 == 0 ) // Minus 2 because you don't start at 0 but at 2.
    {
        echo '</tr><tr>';
    }
    echo '<td><a href="http://www.mysite.net/' . $x . '/"><img src="http://www.mysite.net/' . $x . '/5.jpg" width=200></a></td>';
}

echo '</tr></table>';
```

The `%` is a Math function called modulo. More info can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation).

Comment: Did you notice, that you may want to put `$x - 2` instead of `$z - 2`?

Comment: Thnx for the notice, I think it's a typo.

Answer (score 0):

Use a counter variable.

```
$z = range(2, 123);

$current_result=0;

echo '<table width="100%">';
echo '<tr>';
foreach($z as $x){
if ($current_result++ % 6 == 0) echo '</tr><tr>';

echo '<td><a href="http://www.mysite.net/' . $x . '/"><img src="http://www.mysite.net/' . $x . '/5.jpg" width=200></a></td>';
}
echo '</tr>';
echo '</table>';`
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, for a start `range(2, 123)` is going to produce 122 numbers, so what you want is `range(1, 6)`.

Then you need to fix your script to enclose each table cell in a row element, so your script becomes:

```
$z = range(1, 6);
echo '<table width="100%">';

foreach($z as $x){
  echo '<tr><td><a href="http://www.mysite.net/' . $x . '/"><img src="http://www.mysite.net/' . $x . '/5.jpg" width=200></a></td></tr>';
}

echo '</table>';
```

Range is a bit of an oddball way of looping 6 times though - you might want to just use a string to build up the table and loop using `while`, then output the whole table in 1 go.

**Edit**
Seems I may have missed a point - if you are trying to loop 6 times within the range, then the modulo approach is what you want, although my point about the table row element is still needed otherwise you're not producing valid HTML.

Answer (score 0):

just use any variable for count inside cycle. Increment it and check for you value.
For example

```
$cnt++;
if ($cnt >= 6) {
  $cnt = 0;
  echo "</tr><tr>";
}
```

And don't use foreach. Use for from 2 to 123